# Unable to adjust the BODY width with CSS

Tags: css, document-body

I need body to have a silver background and fill only 75% of the page. That is,  only 75% of the page is painted silver, while the remaining part is unused and painted according to broswer's defaults. The left part of the page is my BODY, the right part is unused. I tried

```
body {
    background-color: silver;
    width: 75%;
}
```

But still the whole page is painted silver. How can I accomplish my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the background color for both `html` and `body`.

In addition you have set a height of `100%` to the `html` element and a `min-height` of `100%` or `100vh` to the `body` so that it will alway fill the whole height of the screen.

The `padding: 0` and `margin: 0`  are important so that you won't have a border between your `body` and the window.

But be award that this will work only for modern browsers. I can't test older browsers right now,  but it would assume that this will have problems with in IE below the version 9 or 10.

So if you want to support older browsers too, then you would need to use the solutions provided by the other answer and use a `div` as container for your content.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 75%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how it Works.
U might use a container as

```
<div id="container"></div>
#container{
    background-color: silver;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I tried it before but this methodology leaves ugly white spaces between DIVs

Comment: white spaces ? How ? Just Place all other divs inside this DIV. Simple

Comment: If the OP does not use a reset style sheet or does not set the margin/padding to `0` for `html` and `body`,  then there would  be a space between the `div` and the window, because of default margins and paddings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a container div for this purpose:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: silver;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Another approach (if you don't need the right border for the content) would be to use background gradients:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, silver 0%, silver 75%, white 75%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, silver 0%, silver 75%, white 75%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have several DIVs inside the BODY. Is it possible to remove white spaces between them?

Comment: Yes, depends on your markup. See this post: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: You should not use a vendor prefix only solution as your answer. If you use vendor prefixes then alway include the standard version of the css property within the css rule. E.g. `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, silver 0%, silver 75%, white 75%); background: linear-gradient(to right, silver 0%, silver 75%, white 75%);`

Comment: A sorry, forgot to add these... O:)